# Django: Scheduled executeion of tasks

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks

I'm building a Django system that needs to daily fetch data from another source (e.g. a daily dump of JSON files from a government site).
The Django site is supposed to run in Docker, currently as a single server but optionally scaling later.
I'd like to run the scheduled task internally inside Django (not using crontab or SystemD), but unsure how to do that.
The schedule isn't dynamic (I'm happy setting the cadence in the Python code), and I don't want to have to run an external command aside from `runserver`.

All of the solutions I found seem to necessitate running another component / command / process, and I wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Celery (with celery beat) https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/
2. Django-Q https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

just follow the documentation to implement scheduled task in Django if you find any difficulty feel free to ask me

Comment: I might be missing something, but it seems #1 requires Celery being installed externally, and #2 needs `$ python manage.py qcluster` executed externally to `runserver`. I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require external components / commands

Comment: I ended up using django-q with the ORM broker. It still requires a separate process (Docker in my case), but at least keeps the same datastore